# OpenWRT web based MP3 player

Tags: php, bash, openwrt

I've successfully install madplay on my router and it run normally if I execute from putty. Now my question is, how I can run it from web interface. currently I've already a php page which display list of mp3 from my song folder.

on putty I can play it with

> madplay -Q "folder-name/name-of-my.file.mp3"

So far I create 3 file, index.php, play.php, play.sh

File structures

```
  /www
   |- cgi-bin
          |- play.sh
   |- musicplayer
          |- index.php
          |- play.php
```

**index.php**, used to listing my mp3 file

```html
$dir = "path-to-mp3-folder";
$files = scandir($dir);

$awal = 2;
while($awal < count($files)) {

    echo "<tr><td><a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"play('" . $files[$awal] . "')\">" . $files[$awal] . "</a></td></tr>";

    $awal++;

}
<script type="text/javascript">

function play(e){var t={lagu:e};$.ajax({url:"http://router-ip/musicplayer/play.php",type:"POST",data:t,success:function(e){},error:function(e){alert("Kesalahan URL")}})}

</script>
```

**play.php**, used to hit play.sh inside cgi-bin folder

```html
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if(isset($_POST['lagu'])) {
    $lagu = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $_POST['lagu']);
    exec('killall -9 madplay');
    exec('echo "' . $lagu . '" > /tmp/playedmp3');
    //exec('sh /www/cgi-bin/play.sh');
exec('curl http://router-ip/cgi-bin/play.sh');
    echo $lagu;
} else {
    echo "Tidak Ada Lagu Terpilih";
} ?>
```

**play.sh** (inside cgi-bin folder)

```html
#!/bin/bash

LAGU=`cat /tmp/playedmp3`

PUTAR="/www/musicplayer/lagu/$LAGU"

killall -9 madplay

nohup madplay -Q $PUTAR &
```

When I try to access index.php and click on mp3 names, no error, but no mp3 played like if I run it from putty shell.

Comment: Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: updated with script i made so far, thanks

Comment: sorry, but it's not clear. You have some music file on router and you are trying to play them from console over SSH, right?